# Elasticsearch - many small documents vs fewer large documents?

Tags: performance, hash, elasticsearch

I'm creating a search by image system(similar to Google's reverse image search) for a cataloging system used internally at my co.. We've already been using Elasticsearch with success for our regular search functionality, so I'm planning on hashing all our images, creating a separate index for them, and using it for searching. There are many items in the system and each item may have multiple images associated with it, and the item should be able to be find-able by reverse image searching any of its related images.

There are 2 possible schema we've thought of:

Making a document for each image, containing only the hash of the image and the item id it is related to. This would result in about ~7m documents, but they would be small since they only contain a single hash and an ID.

Making a document for each item, and storing the hashes of all the images associated with it in an array on the document. This would result in around ~100k documents, but each document would be fairly large, some items have hundreds of images associated with them.

Which of these schema would be more performant?

Comment: Also depends if the associated images can be updated on the document? This could prove costly (update is a delete and index operation after-all))

Answer (score 0):

Having attended a recent [Under the Hood](https://www.elastic.co/videos/speed-is-key-elasticsearch-under-the-hood) talk by Alexander Reelsen, he would probably say "it depends" and "benchmark it".

As @Science_Fiction already hinted:

1. are the images frequently updated? That could come at a negative cost factor
2. OTOH, the overhead for 7m documents maybe shouldn't be neglected whereas in your second scenario they would just be `not_analyzed` terms in a field.

If 1. is a low factor I would probably start with your second approach first.